# Zookeeper Solr integration

Tags: search, solr, distributed, sharding, apache-zookeeper

I have been trying out the Solr [trunk](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk) suggested in SolrCloud which has `ZooKeeper` integration.

When I try `Example C` i.e. `Two shard cluster with shard replicas and ZooKeeper ensemble` I have not been able to run this example on Ubuntu or on Windows. There are socket connecting errors when starting the first server, hence can't proceed.

I would like to find more info on how Solr is integrating with ZooKeeper (what ZooKeeper constructs it is using).

I have read a lot of ZooKeeper material, but there is very little info of Solr in Sharding & distributed search.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you check out the [ZooKeeperIntegration](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ZooKeeperIntegration) and [DeploymentofSolrCoreswithZooKeeper](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DeploymentofSolrCoreswithZookeeper) documentation pages on the Solr Wiki. These seem to have some more details on setting up Solr distributed search with ZooKeeper.